# Code upgrade in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have below code in vue.js method.

```
if(element == 'name'){
   var address_data = {
   name : this.name 
  }
}
```

I would like to replace `name` using `element` like below

```
if(element == 'name'){
   var address_data = {
   element : this.element 
  }
}
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Use regular indexing to object? `this[element]`

Comment: Thanks @SamiKuhmonen. Your solution is working. Thanks.

Comment: You clearly stated you want an object that has a property named `element`. If `element` is used to describe a variable property name, why not include that information outright? Instead you downvote an answer that correctly solved the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EZ PZ like this:

```
if (element == 'name') {
   var address_data = { element }
}
```

If `element` is a variable holding the name of the property in `address_data` which you want to set, and also the name of the property on `this`, go like this:

```
if (element == 'name') {
    var address_data = {}
    address_data[element] = this[element]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @connexo. But it is not working. It is working like `{element: "name"}`. But I need `{name: " value of this.name"}`. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu That is not what your question asked for.